# Yii2 : How to change db connection string dynamically?

Tags: php, database, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I want to change databases connection string and its credentials
on runtime.

I Have master database and many children databases.
And want to switch databses string and its credentials stored in master DB.

not like this  **Yii::$app->db**, **Yii::$app->db2**, .. connections name

Comment: Can you explain more what is your purpose? Do you want to change your database dynamically? Why don't you create your `CustomActiveRecord` model and there use function `setDB` to set your database depends on your conditions?

Comment: we want to switch database according to authorizated person which belongs to different organizations with seperate DB

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to switch DB
Yii provides to set or override component by **Yii::$app->set()** function.
So we can override it any where within application.

In case of globally change the database, we can override it in **on beforeRequest** accrding to condition

In **config/main.php**

```
'components'=>[
    ...
],
'on beforeRequest' => function() {
    $model = app\models\MainFY::findOne(Yii::$app->session->get('activeSession'));
    Yii::$app->set('db', [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => $model->db_string,
        'username' => $model->db_username,
        'password' => $model->db_password,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'enableSchemaCache' => !YII_DEBUG,
    ]);
},
```

in model **app\models\MainFY** , I am using main DB connection

```
public static function getDb() {
    return Yii::$app->dbMain;
}
```